# Pyspark - read periodically from an incremental hive table

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, hive, apache-spark-sql, spark-streaming

I am working on a use case with pyspark.
My pyspark job should read from Hive tables periodically and apply some aggregations and transformations on top of it.
But I cant read the full table each time as i would need to append the output to another table.Can anyone please suggest any ideas. One approach I am thinking is to keep track of the rowId or rownum of the hive table after each process.
Ps: this is not a streaming useCase

Note: I am new to spark.

Thanks,
Albin

Comment: I'm sorry it's not clear why you can't read the entire table.  Could you explain?

Comment: Do mean to say that you calculate some aggregations, but then only want to calculate the new values that were added since your last run? (For performance reasons?)

Comment: @MattAndruff , yes the table I read from is an incremental table and my spark job should periodically(say every 3 mins) read from this table apply transformation and save to new table.I should not read the rows which I have already processed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lets break the problem down.

1. Create two tables to replace the existing one:

   1. Create a Base table, and a Delta table.
2. Create a view that is the union of both tables.
   (Used to give you a complete view of all data as of 'now'.  Excluded
   "Processing" tagged data from the view.  I'll explain why later.)
3. When data is added it's added to the delta table.
4. When it's time to start processing data: Tag the data in the delta table as "Processing"
5. Copy "Processing" data to the Base table, and complete any required Process/update to aggregations.
6. Delete the "Processing" data from the delta table once you have completed your calculations.

It's hopefully now clear why you'd exclude data tagged with "Processing" from your view of 'now'.

Comment: Thanks @matt-andruff, and extremely sorry for the late response.